# Generate animated text with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I have an animated model, which I set below.

```
# Animation Method
    def init():
        line1.set_data([], [])
        line2.set_data([], [])
        line3.set_data([], [])
        ttl.set_text('')

        return line1, line2, line3, ttl

# Animation function
    def animate(i):
        earth_orbit = 40
        planet_orbit = 200
        sun_orbit = 100
        tm_yr = 'Elapsed time = ' + str(round(t[i], 1)) + ' years'
        ttl.set_text(tm_yr)
        line1.set_data(earth_position[i:max(1, i - earth_orbit):-1, 0],
                       earth_position[i:max(1, i - earth_orbit):-1, 1])
        line2.set_data(planet_position[i:max(1, i - planet_orbit):-1, 0],
                       planet_position[i:max(1, i - planet_orbit):-1, 1])
        line3.set_data(sun_position[i:max(1, i - sun_orbit):-1, 0],
                       sun_position[i:max(1, i - sun_orbit):-1, 1])
        return line1, line2, line3, ttl
```

When calling the animation function, everything BUT THE TEXT works
Basically, it should display "Elapsed time= 1,2,3,4,... years"

Here's the code for that

```
 line1, = ax.plot([], [], 'o-', color='#d2eeff', markevery=1000, markerfacecolor='#0077BE', lw=2)
    line2, = ax.plot([], [], 'o-', color='#e3dccb', markersize=8, markerfacecolor='#f66338', lw=2,
                     markevery=1000)
    line3, = ax.plot([], [], 'o-', color="#FDB813", markevery=1000, markersize=8, markerfacecolor="#FDB813",
                     markeredgecolor="#FD7813", lw=2)
    ttl, = ax.text(4.5, 8.3, color='white')
```

Now, I know it misses argument 's', and when trying with label, it won't let me create a label.
The other three lines plot and animate as they should, so I am just wondering where did my text set up go wrong